# Excel VB - Correct chart and formatting

Tags: excel, vba, bar-chart

I'm creating a chart in Excel. I'd like a different version of the chart and not sure what it would be called or if I need to do something else in the code.

There's two questions here.

1. I would like the colorful version of the chart. Do I use something other than xlBarClustered?
2. Notice the labels on the left hand side.  I'd like these as the legend positioned to the right but it seems to think my legend is the header for column F.

I have two images:

the worksheet example:
[image: one is the worksheet example],

desired chart:
[image: the second is the chart I'm trying to achieve.]

Here's the current code:

```
Sub CreateChart()
'
' CreateChart Macro
' Creates a chart in one worksheet
' Want the range to start with E1, go to the right and down.
' first row  is a header row.

'
       
        
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As Chart
    
    'Set cht = Sheets("Chart 1")
    'Set cht = ActiveChart
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E1:F5")
   
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Percent"
    
    cht.HasTitle = True
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = Cells(2, 3).Value
    cht.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    cht.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Arial"
    
    cht.HasLegend = True
    cht.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionRight
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The images weren't able to post.  Does anyone have any recommendations of how I can show the images?

Comment: I'd like to use this to create charts in many worksheets. I recorded a macro creating the version of the chart that I'd like to make. -- Why can't I use "ActiveChart.", like the macro records, in the code that I posted in the first message?  If you can point me to a great resource for fast learning of charts in VB that would be great too.  I've found tons of stuff but end up looking at different pages for almost everything I look for.  Is there a good single source for chart information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that creating the chart without the use of vba is a much quicker and much more flexible way to get any chart you want, especially if someone requests changes.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-chart-from-start-to-finish-0baf399e-dd61-4e18-8a73-b3fd5d5680c2

Comment: I'm sure you are correct but this is going to be used for hundreds of charts which would be a quick thing to do if I can use this code and have it repeat for all those charts.